# reduce data to be sent over UDP sockets

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, pointers, udp

I am repeatedly sending data over UDP socket. Data is of format.

```
int32_t bid
int32_t ask
int32_t price
```

All fields are conditional. so, I am using 3 additional bits to track which fields are present in the message. And I am writing these fields to char array before sending.

So my format becomes.

```
[ first 3 bits | 5 bits] [ ? 32 ] [ ? 32 ] [ ? 32 ]
```

Problem is that I am wasting 5 bits. I can do dirty pointer airthmetic with binary operations to save those bits but it may be taking away the processing speed. How can I do it cleanly and efficiently in c++ ?

Please provide a simple code snippet for this.

Comment: Are this 5bits waste really a problem? UDP packets add much more overhead (that you can't prevent)

Comment: Btw., `int32_t` is better than int for such purposes

Comment: If you want *processing* speed then you should probably use a 32-bit integer for the "size" field too.

Comment: @deviantfan 64 bits in UDP header. 5 bits waste. Approx ~8% waste. I call MAJOR WASTE. :)

Comment: To expand on the first comment by @deviantfan, the [UDP packet header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure) is 8 bytes. To that comes the [IP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) which is at least 20 bytes. To that comes [the Ethernet frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) which adds even more.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude Nobody said anything about sending the packet through IP

Comment: @GillBates As SomeProgrammerDude mentions, your calculation is not enough. 13byte data + at least 8byte ethernet overhead (at least) + 8 byte UDP + 20 byte IPv4 = 49 byte total length (if one packet has one data thing). And we don't need to say that IP packets exist, that should be clear.

Comment: @deviantfan Each day thousands of bits all over the world are wasted, Do you really want to keep this madness going?

Comment: @deviantfan, thanks, ``int32`` corrected

Comment: @ee2 `int32_t` is not the same as int32

Comment: @GillBates Normally I care much about low footprints (CPU, memory, and everything else) in my software. But in this case, 5 bits vs the additional CPU load is a) a bad tradeoff, b) especially because you can send only whole bytes anyway

Comment: @GillBates, so you are saying to keep it that way. It is used in our high frequency trading platform.

Comment: @ee2 I don't know if GillBates thinks that, but I do. Keep it that way. There's no benefit in doing anything else (again, the packet payload has to be whole bytes anyways. You save nothing and waste CPU power).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already discussed in comments, the first thing is to combine multiple messages into a single UDP packet. And it's not so simple as it can look. The biggest challenge here is to decide the packet size.

The max UDP payload size is [65,507 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure) (I assume it's UDP over IPv4 by default). If UDP payload size is bigger than MTU size UDP will [silently segment the packet](https://serverfault.com/a/601781/93128). In real life UDP packets size usually is equal or less than MTU size. But even MTU size (~1500 bytes) can be too big. There was some research for multimedia streaming application that stated that large UDP packets were more often dropped if network was congested and recommended to use something like 400 bytes payload size as a good balance between a chance to be dropped and to not waste bandwidth for UDP/IP headers. Again, it depends on your application, mainly on your data traffic.

Then, you can apply different compression techniques. `bid` can be compressed by e.g. [Variable Length Encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code) or [Run Length Encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), depends on the nature of your `bid`.

I've no idea what `ask` field is, but `price` looks like a good candidate for a [fixed point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). If `ask` is related to `price` maybe it's worth to send the difference between them and saving some bits.

First of all, decide how many bits per field you really need, then decide how to arrange them to minimise gaps or to optimise performance. Bit manipulation is quite expensive, minimising data copying also can optimise performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you care so much about those 5 bits, then you very probably can save much more by dynamically reducing the size of the fields for the `bid`, `ask` and `price` fields. Then in your header field you can allocate two bits per each of your payload fields for holding three possible values:

- 0 - the field is not present
- 1 - the field is present and is encoded in 16 bits
- 2 - the field is present and is encoded in 32 bits

Answer (score 2):

I think the devil is in the detail in these things. It might be wise to study the statistics of the message you send for it might be possible to devise a scheme that improves the average performance.

For example if you are sending a bunch of these at a time (so that the comments about the size of the headers could be misplaced) then you could arrange the message block to be eight arrays (each with a count): first the messages with all 3 fields, then the messages with just, say bid and ask and so on. This does add 8 counts to the message, but means you don't send fields that aren't there; whether you save on average will be depend on the size of the blocks and the statistics of the messages. If some of the combinations were rare you could have a type field before the arrays that specifies which types are there.

Another thing to consider is whether you could steal some bits from the fields. For example, if you had, say, the bid field, do you need the full 32 bits for the others? Could, say, the ask be encoded as a 30 bit difference from the bid?